# Reference request: $\alpha$-Hölder spaces as double duals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space, we define the $\alpha$-Hölder class $\Lambda_\alpha(X)$ as the subset of $C_b(X)$ satisfying that
$$
  \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha}.
$$
Similarly, we can define the Little Hölder space $\lambda_\alpha(X)$ as the subset of functions of $\Lambda_\alpha(X)$ satisfying that
$$
  \lim_{x \to y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha} = 0.
$$
I recall a result stating that, at least in classical contexts like $X = \mathbb{T}^n$, $\Lambda_\alpha(X)$ is isomorphic to the double dual of $\lambda_\alpha(X)$.

> **Question:** Is there any reference for that duality in the context of more general metric spaces? An initial google search didn't yield anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I am not sure what you mean by $L^\infty(X)$ for a general complete metric space $X$. Don't you want $C_b(X)$?

Secondly: when $X$ is compact and $0<\alpha<1$, the result you want is Theorem 3.5 in

> W. G. Bade, P. C. Curtis, Jr, and H. G. Dales,
>   *Amenabilty and weak amenability for Beurling and Lipschitz algebras.*
>   Proc. London Math. Soc. 55 (1987) 359–377.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The result is proven in a more general setting, which includes noncompact $X$, in Theorem 4.38 of my book *Lipschitz Algebras*, second edition.

Comment: I suspected as much, but I don't have a copy of your book, so I thought I would go with the reference that I happened to know for sure :)

Comment: Thanks. Thant was a nice read!